# Eclipse: Project properties-->Android-->Library-->Add is always off

Tags: android, eclipse

I am going to add one project as a library for the other one. To do that I try to

**Project properties-->Android-->Library-->Add** , but when i push the Add button it's always off and there is nothing to select?

(I have put my library project into the user project folder, but still not working )

[image]

Comment: Try checking the "is library" for the project your trying to add as library, and then try adding again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, offen you need

1.Create Project A

1.1. Open Properties

1.2. Android

1.3. Library set **Is Library** checked

1.4. Save It

2.Create Project B

2.1. Open Properties

2.2. Android

2.3. Add Library - here you will see your Project A

Also checkout Android API Versions of projects.

Answer (score 1):

Library project should be an independent project (not inside any other project). Make sure that "is library" is ticked inside your library project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you have to check 2 things:

- First, the library project that you want to add must be imported into your workspace in ADT. To do so, go to File->Import Project and select your Library project
- When done it, the Library project must have the "Is Library" checkbox selected in its properties.

When you have checked these 2 thing you will see your library project in the list

Answer (score 0):

Its deactivated, because you don't have a library project in your eclipse workspace. You can create a Android library project like described her: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject